Two occurrences of a variable declared with 'my' but in two different packages in the same file
I haven't coded anything in Perl for a long time. Now I have started again and came across an interesting situation when coding two packages within a single '.pm' file. Until now I thought that if I define two packages in a file (e.g. ConfigData and RuntimeData), I can define a variable (declared with 'my') with the same name (e.g. my $instance) for each package without conflicts. As an example, here is a minimal code to illustrate this:
package Jabs::ConfigData;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $instance;
sub new {
        my ($class) = @_;
        unless (defined $instance) {
                $instance = bless {}, $class;
        }
        return $instance;
}
1;  # End of 'ConfigData'

package Jabs::RuntimeData;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $instance;
sub new {
        my ($class) = @_;
        unless (defined $instance) {
                $instance = bless {}, $class;
        }
        return $instance;
}
1;  # End of 'RuntimeData'

I called perl -c test2.pm and got the following message as feedback:
"my" variable $instance masks earlier declaration in same scope at test2.pm line 27.
test2.pm syntax OK

Now it is not clear to me why the scope should be the same. Because 'my $instance is defined in two different packages.
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and Perl5 (revision 5 version 38 subversion 2)
Can someone perhaps provide me with an explanation for my comprehension problem?

The related perldoc -f my says that my variables are: " local (lexically) to the enclosing block, file, or eval." The package keyword does not include such a scope. Although the documentation for package mentions BLOCK, so perhaps you can add a block to the package keyword to enforce a lexical scope to separate "my" variables.

More info in https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod#Packages

Re "Because 'my $instance is defined in two different packages", Lexical variables very specifically aren't package variables. That the whole point of them. /// Re "Now it is not clear to me why the scope should be the same.", Why wouldn't they be?

Thank you very much for the explanations. I have learned (contrary to my assumption) that packages are not implicit blocks. Therefore, I now understand that the scope remains the same, even if I have defined the variable in two packages with 'my'.

Again, they're not defined in a package. my variables very specifically aren't package variables.

The related perldoc -f my says:

A my declares the listed variables to be local (lexically) to the enclosing block, file, or eval.

The package keyword in the form of package NAME does not include such a scope. Although the documentation for package mentions you can declare a package with a block, e.g. package NAME BLOCK. At the bottom is my demonstration of such blocks.
perldoc perlmod elaborates:

A package statement affects only dynamic global symbols, including subroutine names, and variables you've used local() on, but not lexical variables created with my(), our() or state().


use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

package Conf {  # <-- block start
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    
    my $instance;
    sub new {
            my ($class) = @_;
            unless (defined $instance) {
                    $instance = bless {}, $class;
            }
            $instance->{foo} = "Confs";
            return $instance;
    }
    1;
} # <-- block end END OF CONF

package eData { # <-- block start
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    
    my $instance;
    sub new {
        my ($class) = @_;
        unless (defined $instance) {
                $instance = bless {}, $class;
        }
        $instance->{foo} = "eDatas";
        return $instance;
    }
    1;
} # <-- block end END OF EDATA

my $c1 = Conf->new;    # loads the first $instance 
my $c2 = eData->new;   # loads the other $instance, different variable and scope

say $c1->{foo};
say $c2->{foo};

Outputs:
Confs
eDatas


Thank you very much for the explanation. As in my comment above, I have now learned that packages are not implicit blocks. Your example helped me a lot with coding and to understand exactly what was going on. It answered my question completely.

@autio Happy to help!

The short answer is that the package variables and lexical variables are two separate variable tracking systems that have nothing to do with each other.
A package variable is effectively global. It exists at all times and places in the program as long as you know the fully-qualified package name (such as main::foo). The package statement merely changes the default package to use. The local temporarily replaces the value of package variable in a scope (containing block or file).
The lexical variables are completely controlled by scope (containing block or file), that contains the declaration (my).
In your case, both instances of my $instance appear in the same scope (the file).
But, it looks like you are trying to create two singleton classes where you either return the thing you already created or create it on first use.
Perl v5.10's state lets you move that variable into the subroutine. That's a persistent lexical variable. And, the // (defined-or) let's you use a binary assignment to make things simple:
use v5.12;

package Foo { # block package needs v5.12, not necessary for problem
    sub new {
            state $instance; # needs v5.10;
            return $instance //= bless {}, $_[0];
    }
}

You can do the same thing prior to v5.10 by defining your new inside a scope that contains the $instance. Now that $instance only exists in that scope:

package Foo;
    {
    my $instance;
    sub new {
            return $instance if defined $instance;
            $instance = bless {}, $_[0];
        }
    }

package main;

...


hi brian, remember that //= is also version-dependent on v5.10. That said, I see little need for any //, //=, or defined operators here given how a simpler boolean true-vs-false should always suffice for any object—since all objects are “always true by definition”, any sneaky overloading notwithstanding. I mention this mostly because I find perl code that can manage to correctly do its job using only a basic boolean test (rather than defined, let alone exists) to be inherently shorter, simpler, and easier to understand than the contrary proposition, and so more desirable.

state $instance; return $instance //= bless {}, $_[0]; can be simplified to state $instance = bless {}, $_[0]; return $instance;, You could even use return state $instance = bless {}, $_[0];

The bottom snippet is rather appalling. $instance = bless {}, $_[0] if !defined $instance; return $instance; would be much clearer, and I'd use return $instance ||= bless {}, $_[0];

"clear" is something that depends on the person or team reading it. You might like to move around the parts, but you're essentially talking bout style here. If you want to write it like that, that's up to you and I wouldn't describe it as "appalling". In the context of SO, I tend to expand rather than compress because many people needing help may not have the code reading fu to pick apart multiple features in the same statement.
